# 415 error while calling post API from jersey client

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have below API which returns back the access_token.

POST  https://idcs-xxxxxxxxxbf08128c3d93a19c.identity.c9dev2.oc9qadev.com/oauth2/v1/token

in header `content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. also in body it contains below parameter.

[image]

I send user name and password and it is secured with basic authentication. It provides access_token when I call from postman. also it provides output when I consume using `HttpUrlConnection`

```
          url = new URL(tokenURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
        osw.write("grant_type=client_credentials&scope=" + scope);
```

**The above code is working properly. But when I use jersey it gives 415 error. I am using below code.**

```
String user="idcs-oda-zzzxxxxxf93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0_APPID";       
    String password="xxxxxxx-6f71-4af2-b5cc-9110890d1456";
    String scope = "https://idcs-oda-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1";
    String tokenURL = "https://idcs-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx28c3d93a19c.identity.c9dev2.oc9qadev.com/oauth2/v1/token";
    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature= HttpAuthenticationFeature
                                .basicBuilder()
                                .nonPreemptive()
                                .credentials(user,password)
                                .build();
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.register(feature);
    
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
    WebTarget webTarget= client.target(tokenURL);
    PostDetails post= new PostDetails("client_credentials",scope);  //Bean class to assign body parameter
    Response response= webTarget.request()
                       .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                       .post(Entity.json(post)); 
    System.out.println(response);
```

Can somebody tell me what mistake I am doing in Response line.

Comment: Please edit your [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63154167/error-415-while-calling-api-form-jersey-client) instead of creating duplicates

Comment: Actually, I have given here more details. I will delete the older one. can you please help. I am really struggling

Comment: webTarget.request("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") what is this for?

Comment: Thanks Santosh.. i actually removed that and checked, still it was giving 415 error.

Comment: You didnt set this   connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); why?

Comment: I earlier put in the request. how to put in jersey?

Comment: webTarget.request()
                       .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                       .header('Accept','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
                       .post(Entity.json(post));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your Accept on the [request](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html) method:

```java
Response response= webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                       .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                       .post(Entity.json(post));
```

You also need to ensure that if your API accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content, that is what you are sending.

Currently, you are sending `application/json` content based on your usage of `Entity.json(post)`.

I don't know what type is assigned to `post`, but you need to figure out how to convert it either to a [`Form`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Form.html) or a [`MultiValuedMap<String,String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html), and then use the `form` method on [`Entity`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html) to submit your content.

```java
Response response= webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                       .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                       .post(Entity.form(postForm)); //assuming postForm typed as Form or MultiValuedMap<String,String>
```

Taking a guess regarding `post`, creating `postForm` as a `MultiValuedMap<String,String>` may be as simple as the following (which you would place prior to your request, of course).

```java
MultiValuedMap<String,String> postForm = new MultiValuedHashMap<>();
postForm.add("client_credentials",scope);
```

Comment: Philip, can there be other issue?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is:

```
Response response= webTarget.request()
    .accept("application/json") // Accept field from header of request
    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") //manually set content-tyoe
    .post(Entity.entity(input, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)); // request body
```

The best way to see what is Jersey actually is sending is to register logger, and log network. For example:

```
clientConfig.register(
    new LoggingFeature(
            new Slf4jLogger(this.getClass().getName(), null)));
```

where Slf4jLogger is from `org.apache.cxf:cxf-core`.

Comment: I am getting this error. MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, type=class org.studyeasy.showroom.resources.PostDetails, genericType=class org.studyeasy.showroom.resources.PostDetails.

Comment: Try to set content-type with `.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`. And use `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` so that jersey pick text writer for entity deserialization.